# Java JPanel two borders, different colors?

Tags: java, swing, border

For my layout i want to have double borders, on the bottom of my JPanel, one should be slightly darker and the other should be slightly lighter.

Currently i have 1 border:

```
JPanel pnlTop = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                new java.awt.Color(237, 237, 237), 0, getHeight(),
                new java.awt.Color(222, 222, 222));
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); 
    }
};
pnlTop.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, new java.awt.Color(173, 173, 166)));
pnlTop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2000, 90));
add(pnlTop, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

How could i add another border underneath the one that i already have? Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a `CompoundBorder`

ie...

```
pnlTop.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLUE), 
    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.RED));
```

See [How to use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: Nice to have helped :)

Comment: Also, don't forget, you can use `CompoundBorder`s within `CompoundBorder`